# Centralizar texto dentro de uma imagem no div

Tags: css, wordpress

Tenho um pequeno problema neste blog que trabalho, http://bloganacastro.com

As grids de posts logo abaixo da logo estão funcionando tudo OK, porém, como podem ver o texto (título do post) quando o mouse fica encima não fica no meio corretamente, responsivo, por exemplo quebrando a linha para evitar que suma o texto. Tenho este blog por exemplo que funciona da forma que gostaria http://www.sempreglamour.com.br/ tentei alguns códigos no CSS porém sem sucesso. Alguém sabe algum método que faça funcionar desta maneira?

Comment: qual o navegador que você usa para fazer os testes? Eu olhei o site aqui no Chrome e não teve falha alguma!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione isso e veja se resolve:

```
.caption, .caption-text{
   width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Amigo, perfeito. Deu certo! Utilizei o height com 100% também para ficar perfeito. Apenas textos realmente grandes que corta uma parte. Notei apenas que o texto ainda se mantém à esquerda do quadrado, não ao centro. Será alguma outra configuração? Mesmo estando com align center.